# Using a user defined slot in PyQt

Tags: pyqt

I have a problem using signal and slot to use a push button to trigger an event that calls "gc.speed_rpm"(a used defined slot, or my own method/function) and display the output of it on a text browser widget.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.textBrowser_2, gc.speed_rpm)
```

I received the following error:

```
arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(),     Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 4 has unexpected type 'instancemethod'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'QTextBrowser'
```

What could go wrong? Any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using new style signals and slots. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/24/new-style-signal-slot-connection-mechanism-in-pyqt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self):
  # Connect the clicked action of the push button to a custom slot
  self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.display_speed_rpm)

def display_speed_rpm(self):
  # Use of setPlainText or setHtml depends on the output of gc.speed_rpm()
  self.textBrowser_2.setPlainText(gc.speed_rpm())
```

Edit: you can also use the decorator way to connect a widget signal to a slot. You must name your slot according to the widget name and signal name:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
  # Use of setPlainText or setHtml depends on the output of gc.speed_rpm()
  self.textBrowser_2.setPlainText("{}".format(gc.speed_rpm()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frodon, this works if I use with self.label.setNum(gc.speed_rpm()). As for textBrowser there is no such "setNum" interface, how should I achieve this, or typecast it?

Comment: @alfa_80: so I understand that gc.speed_rpm() return a numeric value. You can try setPlainText("%.d"%gc.speed_rpm()) if the speed rpm is an integer, or setPlainText("%.4f"%gc.speed_rpm()) if the speed rpm is a float and you need a 4 digits precision, or even setPlainText(str(gc.speed_rpm()) if you don't want to precisely control the display.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly! Anyway, I'm just wondering why the " setPlainText" which is expecting a QString can also accept str(which is native python typecast)..Thanks again..

Comment: PyQt maps the Python str into a QString. The reverse is not true: when you receive a QString, you probably need to use str(theQString) on it to use in a pure Python function.